# Is a POST request with an empty body and a response of a pure ID value in text format RESTful

Tags: rest, jax-rs, rpc

In our *REST API* project with a *jax-rs* based framework, there is one customer *endpoint*:

`customer/`

This endpoint has a *POST* method with an **empty input body**, and the **response** with status SUCCESS (201) is just an automatically generated **ID value in pure text format**, meaning neither *JSON* nor *XML*.

**Question 1: is it normal to make a POST request with an empty input body in a RESTful API?**

**Question 2: Is the implementation of returning only a value in pure text format still a valid RESTful API? Is this implementation a good practice at all? What is the problem of such implementation? How to improve it?** Personally I really feel odd on such implementation but I am really not able to tell the problem of it

If I implement the POST method, I probably would return a JSON or an xml format response instead of a pure text value, sth like:

`{id: 1234567}`

Comment: Yes returning a JSON object is better. So that you have consistent API and only need to handle JSON response.

Answer (score 1):

Having an endpoint accept an empty POST request is fine. If that has a sensible meaning in your context, that's entirely valid. And it sounds like this creates a new numbered resource which does not *require* any parameters in order to be created, so the use case is perfectly fine. There may or may not be a better overall design you could use instead of a design where you create a new resource without parameters, but nobody can tell without knowing more details.

As for returning plaintext content, that's *generally* also entirely valid if it makes sense for your use case. It's a good idea to be *consistent* across your API, but there's no inherent technical *need* for it. For example, if some of your endpoints return binary data (say, a PDF file), it would make absolutely zero sense to wrap that in JSON or XML or whatever just for consistency's sake. So mixed response types across your API are generally no issue.

Having said that, if some of your endpoints return JSON and others XML and yet others plaintext, that may be somewhere between confusing and annoying to the consumer of the API, as they need to anticipate various different response formats, which is more complex than only needing to expect one response format.

Answer (score 0):

Yes returning a JSON object is better. So that you have consistent API and only need to handle JSON response.

Comment: The Content-Type header indicates what format the response is in, and a truly RESTful API and consumer should arguably be content-type agnostic; you can serialize the same data in different, equivalent formats after all. So, while it may be a good idea to keep things consistent, it’s not a must in any way. So this is merely an opinion.

Comment: @deceze So "consistent" means that if one request in the endpoint returns pure text as output, all the other requests should return pure text, right?

Comment: @Rui Yes. Or conversely, if any of your other endpoints return JSON or XML, then *all* should return JSON or XML. Again, there's no technical reason for it, it just makes it easier for the consumer of the API as they can have consistent expectations. But it really depends on your specific situation. E.g., if one endpoint would return binary data (say, a PDF), then it makes no sense to bend over backwards and wrap that in JSON just for consistency's sake.

Answer (score 0):

> Is it normal to make a `POST` request with an empty input body in a RESTful API?

In [`POST`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3) requests, the server processes the representation sent in the request payload according to the resource's own specific semantics. If no representation is required, then an empty payload is *acceptable*. Quoting the [RFC 7231](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231):

> [**4.3.3.  POST**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-4.3.3)
>
> The `POST` method requests that the target resource process the representation enclosed in the request according to the resource's own specific semantics.

---

> Is the implementation of returning only a value in pure text format still a valid RESTful API? Is this implementation a good practice at all? What is the problem of such implementation? How to improve it?

If a resource has been created as a result of this request, you must return [`201`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.2). If the newly created resource resides in a different URI than the target URI, then you must return a [`Location`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.2) header.

> [**6.3.2.  201 Created**](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-6.3.2)
>
> The `201` (Created) status code indicates that the request has been fulfilled and has resulted in one or more new resources being created.  The primary resource created by the request is identified by either a `Location` header field in the response or, if no `Location` field is received, by the effective request URI.

Along with the [`Location`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.2) header, you can return a resource identifier in the payload, if you wish to.